# GridView is not shown in the content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview in my Master page.I have taken an item template inside it. I have given some text to the controls initially.
In the design view of the content page gridview is visible but while running the page it's not showing gridview.
when i deleted gridview and put some simple text in place of it ,it's working .

i tried setting z- index and some peculiar things but nothing seems to work.Please help me out

Comment: Do you have any rows bound to the grid based on which it would generate rows and display your text ? else its just a template which needs some rows available to spring into action

Comment: Is the gridview appearing in the client side source code? What are you binding to? Are there any items in your DataSource?

Comment: put code of girdview column defination  and properties..  check for the datasource settings..

Answer (score 2):

There may be number of causes - you might not bind it or `datasource` is empty or its visibility state is `hidden` or you have placed `GridView` inside the `ContantPlaceHolder` in master page.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the below cases to show the gridview, listed below:

a. Must have to put "DataSource" and then call DataBind() method, like

```
gridViewToShow.DataSource = dataSourceName; // may be table or custom data source
gridViewToShow.DataBind();
```

b. Data must exists in the "DataSource"
c. Locate data field( <%# Eval("DataFieldName") %> ) to Gridview column, like in aspx code 
c. Make it visible (or don't make invisible, by default it is true)
d. If you use CssClass, then make sure there has "display:block;" or has no "display:none;"

Hope these would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `EmptyDataText` to something and see if it shows the text. If it does, it means it is not `DataBound` to anything, or the `DataSource` has no rows. Good luck!